# Json string with nested objects to Map<String,String>

Tags: java, json

I have a json string with possible nested object inside like this:

```
{
    "stringTypeCode": "aaaaa",
    "choiceTypeCode1": {
        "option1": true,
        "option2": true
    },
    "choiceTypeCode2": {
        "option3": true,
        "option4": true
    }
}
```

I need it to convert to a Map leaving the nested objects as strings:

```
stringTypeCode - aaaaa
choiceTypeCode1 - {"option1": true,"option2": true}
choiceTypeCode2 - {"option2": true,"option3": true}
```

Can it be done in a simple way, preferably without any library?

Edit: or with a library if there is no other simple way.

Edit2: I have a variable number of properties with variable names in the objects.

Comment: Simple way == use a decent library. Hard way == re-invent the wheel

Comment: at minimum you need a library to deserialise and re-serialise the data from and to JSON. Otherwise you'll have to write your own parser, which is a bit pointless (unless you're practising in order to make a career of such things). The rest is just trivial object manipulation, though.

Comment: And there are *many* similar "how do I parse JSON" questions on this site that will help.

Comment: A json object is essentially a map, its simple enough to create a new object using the member names you have with a simple for loop.

Comment: You can create a POJO class and Jackson library, which will help you to convert. And as @HovercraftFullOfEels said, Search..

Comment: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2591098/how-to-parse-json-in-java)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Parse the json to a map or generic json structure, iterate over the `key - value` pairs, then create a new map from `key - toJsonString(value)` pairs. `value` might be a simple string, json object, number etc...

With a simple Jackson ObjectMapper:

```
String json = "YOUR JSON HERE";
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
Iterator<Entry<String, JsonNode>> fields = mapper.readTree(json).fields();
Map<String, String> m = new HashMap<>();
while (fields.hasNext()) {
    Entry<String, JsonNode> field = fields.next();
    m.put(field.getKey(), mapper.writeValueAsString(field.getValue()));
}
m.entrySet().forEach(e -> System.out.println(e.getKey() + " - " + e.getValue()));
```

Your example produces:

```
stringTypeCode - "aaaaa"
choiceTypeCode1 - {"option1":true,"option2":true}
choiceTypeCode2 - {"option3":true,"option4":true}
```